# React Js material UI not updating the value when set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

so I have this code in material UI react js which is not updating the value properly or so I thought, to explain this further I have this code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';

export function Home() {


const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Pending');

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
      console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          textColor="secondary"
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          aria-label="secondary tabs example"
        >
          <Tab value="Pending" label="Pending" />
          <Tab value="Received" label="Received" />
          <Tab value="Prepared" label="Prepared" />
          <Tab value="Cancelled" label="Cancelled" />
        </Tabs>
        </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I run this code and click on the Tab with the label "Pending" the console.log won't be triggered. if I click again on the Tag with the label "Received" the console.log with displays "Pending" instead of "Received".

This happens all the time I thought when you set the value and console log it should show the latest value you selected.

sample output:

[image]

As you can see am currently selected the "Received" Tag but on the display its showing "Pending"

Is this how react js/Material UI behaves or am I just missing something here?

thanks

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dave Newton said in the comments, setting the state is asynchronous as mentioned in the React Docs here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

If you want to `console.log` the value, you can update your handler to log the new value instead

```
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
  console.log(newValue);
};
```

Or you can use `useEffect` outside the handler to always log `value` when it changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
}, [value]);
```